# Accessing array data from a separate function by calling methods

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to print the data in my lotto numbers array (from my `Main` method) in the way it is already formatted (i.e `4 7 19 23 28 36` on one line and on the next `14 18 26 34 38 45`) etc.

At the moment I seem to be *getting an error* which I believe is telling me that the array is of the *wrong size*? (`IndexOutOfRange` was unhandled)

```
     static void Main() {
       int[,] lottoNumbers = {
         { 4,  7, 19, 23, 28, 36},
         {14, 18, 26, 34, 38, 45},
         { 8, 10, 11, 19, 28, 30},
         {15, 17, 19, 24, 43, 44},
         {10, 27, 29, 30, 32, 41},
         { 9, 13, 26, 32, 37, 43},
         { 1,  3, 25, 27, 35, 41},
         { 7,  9, 17, 26, 28, 44},
         {17, 18, 20, 28, 33, 38},
       };

       int[] drawNumbers = new int[] { 
         44, 9, 17, 43, 26, 7, 28, 19 };

       PrintLottoNumbers(lottoNumbers);

       ExitProgram();
     } // end Main

     static void PrintLottoNumbers(int[,] lottoN) {
       for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
         for (int a = 0; a < 6; a++) {
           Console.Write(lottoN[a, i]);
         }
       }
     } // Print Function For Lotto Numbers
```

Comment: It's rather `lottoN[i, a]`, you switched the indices.

Comment: And maybe in for loop `i <= 8` or `i < 9` in your sample code

Answer (score 4):

Do not use *magic numbers*! What does `8` or `6` stand for?

```
for (int i = 0; i < lottoN.GetLength(0); ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < lottoN.GetLength(1); ++j) 
    Console.Write(lottoN[i, j]);

  //DONE: you, probably, want to print out the array line by line 
  Console.WriteLine();
}
```

**Edit:** You may want to *align* numbers, e.g.

```
  4  7 19 23 28 36
 14 18 26 34 38 45
```

instead of

```
 4 7 19 23 28 36
 14 18 26 34 38 45
```

In this case, you have to privide a *format*, e.g.

```
 Console.Write($"{lottoN[i, j],2}"); // ,2 - ensure length 2; align to the right
```

Answer (score 0):

If the entire array should be printed, the indexing should be changed as follows.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    for (int a = 0; a < 6; a++) {
        Console.Write(lottoN[i, a]);
    }
}
```

That being said, the `GetLength` method, as mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx), can be used to read the actual length of multidimensional arrays.